# Wildcard for Strings in E4X?

Tags: actionscript, wildcard, e4x

I'm trying to solve an Actionscript problem using E4X.
I have an XML like this one:

```
<root>
  <person firstname="john" lastname="doe" age="21" />
  <person firstname="jayne" lastname="doe" age="35" />
  <person firstname="john" lastname="miller" age="42" />
</root>
```

I want to have just one function search() that takes three parameters (firstname, lastname, age) and return an XMLList. So the result could look like this:

```
var result:XMLList = xml..person.(@firstname == firstName && @lastname == lastName && @age == age );
```

But I don't want to use all three parameters all the time. I would like to have a function that uses a 'wilcard' if the parameter is NULL. So if the wildcard would be "*" the function  could look like:

```
searchPerson( firstName:String ="*", lastName:String = "*" , age:String = "*") {...}
```

so that I would only pass 'John' for the firstName I'd get the first and the third node in return.

How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The boolean value of `attribute("your-attribute")` will indicate if a particular attribute is present.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I could check all attributes. But I would be left with 7 different options:

- firstName
- secondName
- age
- firstName && secondName
- firstName && age
- lastName && age
- firstName && secondName && age

I'd prefer a one-liner, that's why I'm looking for something like a wildcard.